# Syntax for -Djava.security.debug codebase

Tags: java, tomcat, java-security, java-12

I'm trying to use the `-Djava.security.debug` command line option to get the permissions requested by a specific .jar file, ignoring all others. I can't seem to find the right syntax to get it to work properly. I've tried the following:

```
-Djava.security.debug=access:domain:codebase=file:/path/to/jar/name.jar
-Djava.security.debug=access:domain:codebase=/path/to/jar/name.jar
-Djava.security.debug=access:domain:codebase=name.jar
-Djava.security.debug=access:domain:codebase=name
-Djava.security.debug=access,domain,codebase=/path/to/jar/name.jar
-Djava.security.debug=access,domain,codebase=name.jar
-Djava.security.debug=access,domain,codebase=name
```

When there is `jar` anywhere in what I put after `codebase=`, I get output as if I had used the `jar` option with `-Djava.security.debug`, and no other output related to `java.security`. When there isn't, I get no output related to `java.security`. The name of my jar includes `jar`, could that be part of the problem?